# Qt Eclipse Integration not working

Tags: eclipse, qt, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I was hoping to use the Qt plugin with Eclipse. The installation is very simple - just expand a tarball in the appropriate directory. After doing so, I can see trolltech folders under eclipse/features and eclipse/plugins. However, when I try to create a project, I see no sign of any Qt option. Nor do I see Qt listed in the Installed Software listing of plugins or features.

Eclipse: Galileo Build 3.5.2
CDT: 6.0.0.2
O/S: Ubuntu 10.10 i686 2.6.35-28-generic

Plugin in tarball: qt-eclipse-integration-linux.x86.1.6.1.tar.gz from here: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration/

Starting Eclipse with -consolelog -debug didn't offer any enlightenment

Have the Qt plugins aged past their use-by date?

**Update**

Installing to /usr/share/eclipse is a mistake

Installing to /usr/lib/eclipse works

I would suggest that that the instructions on the Qt page could use some revision. Instead of saying:

> Find your eclipse/plugins folder

It might be better to add: The eclipse folder should contain the eclipse executable, eclipse.ini, the plugins directory, and the features directory.

This would have kept me from being fooled by /usr/share/eclipse, which has a feature directory and a plugins directory, but is not the correct place to install additional plugins.

Comment: Could you provide some more information?  Where did you un-tar the tarball to?  Do you see any files or folders named "com.trolltech.qt*" in your eclipse/plugins directory?

Comment: Answer: I installed to /usr/share/eclipse, which turns out to be a mistake. Redoing it in /usr/lib/eclipse works.

Comment: Why does everyone call it QT instead of Qt? QT = QuickTime; Qt = Q toolkit.

Comment: @MarkNelson - I ran into the same issue Mark.  I untar'ed to the wrong directory a couple times before realizing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try untaring under the dropins directory instead. Modern versions of Eclipse will not pickup plugins overlaid over the existing plugins and features directories. If dropins doesn't work then these plugins declare dependencies on older versions of eclipse components.

Comment: Even though my version of Eclipse seemingly supports p2, it does not have a dropins folder.

Answer (score 0):

Find out where your eclipse installation lies in terminal. I have mine extracted to ~/tools/eclipse/

```
$ which eclipse
```

Navigate to the folder and extract the plugins into the plugins folder, the features into the features folder.

Start Eclipse back up and go to Window->Preferences->QT. Click Add and navigate to the executable directory. For me as of version 4.8.1 it was in /Qt/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/bin. The includes directory auto updated to /Qt/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include, click Apply and restart if necessary.

After this I can create a new Qt Gui projects, Qt gui classes, Qt resource files and Qt console projects in addition to Qt Designer forms.